# Give an example of a bounded function $f:R\to R$ that has a limit at every point except 2

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Give an example of a bounded function $f:R\to R$ that has a limit at every point except 2

This question is very open ended and I'm not sure where to go with this. I know that if we have a denomator of x-2, then a limit of 2 would not work. Am I on the right track?

Comment: No...$\frac 1{x-2}$ is not  bounded.  Hint;  All you need is a discontinuity at $x=2$.

Comment: @lulu: I don't think that is quite right (the limit could exist at $x = 2$ despite the discontinuity).

Comment: Try the function $f$ defined by: $f(x) = -1$ for $x < 2$; $f(2) = 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x > 2$.

Comment: @RobArthan  True.  I phrased that too strongly.  You want a discontinuity at $2$ but not a removable one.

Answer (score 1):

Hello，here is a function you can consider
y=sin（1/（x-2））。